# Flyweight Pattern in C++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

When creating a flyweight pattern, how does one usually store superflous objects.  Lets say I create an Aircraft.

```
class Aircraft
{
private:
    char make[32];
    char model[32];
    double cruiseSpeed;
    double cruiseAltitude;
    double climbRate;
    double wingspan;
    double fuselageLength;

    AircraftType craftType;

public:

    Aircraft(void);
    Aircraft(AircraftType);
    ~Aircraft(void);

    void setMake(char*);
    void setModel(char*);
    void setCruiseSpeed(double);
    void setCruiseAltitude(double);
    void setClimbRate(double);
    void setWingSpan(double);
    void setFuselageLength(double);

    char* getMake();
    char* getModel();
    double getCruiseSpeed();
    double getCruiseAltitude();
    double getClimbRate();
    double getWingSpan();
    double getFuselageLength();    
};
```

Lets also say I'm reading in many aircrafts from an xml data sheet, so I want to just create one one these objects and store the rest of the information somewhere.  Would I create another class that manages the flyweight information, then maybe pass it a key with the Aircraft object to input into the only instance one at a time?  Or would you just bypass putting the information in the object instance at all?

For this type of object, would the only efficiency gained in not creating multiple instance be the get and sets?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Look at the [boost flyweight implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/flyweight/doc/index.html).
After you do, just use boost flyweight.

If you don't want to use boost, use boost in such case.

Comment: I can't use any external libraries.  And that doesn't really help to answer my question, which is more theoretical about the design itself.

Comment: "If you don't want to use boost, use boost" - what? How does that make sense?

Comment: He means using C++ without Boost is a lot like driving a car without wheels.

Comment: @phs Some seem to enjoy doing that though, inventing (really shoddy) wheels along the way.

Comment: So basically.  If using boost is not allowed, use boost.  Got it, will go not use boost...because that is not possible in this instance.

Comment: @user2079828 Actually, I also did answer your question to a very decent extent, saying there's a really really good implementation ready in boost that you can have a look at. (And then, use it.)